# select multiple sheets with the same range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code below that works perfectly, but I need to alter it to get data from the same range (D5) but from multiple sheets. At the moment, it gets the data from 'Cancellations' only. How would I get it to select D5 from say 'Sheet2', or 'Sheet3' as well.
I have included half of the code from the function I currently have. As you can see it's very repatative.

```
    function transferList() {

///////////////////////////////////////////Export value 1/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var columnIndex = 1; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(2,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(3,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);
  
  var columnIndex = 1; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Unanswered");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(2,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(3,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

  var columnIndex = 1; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Queries");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(2,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(3,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);





///////////////////////////////////////////Export value 2/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var columnIndex = 4; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

  var columnIndex = 4; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Unanswered");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

  var columnIndex = 4; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Queries");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);


///////////////////////////////////////////Export value 3////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 var columnIndex = 7; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D7").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

   var columnIndex = 7; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Unanswered");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D7").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

   var columnIndex = 7; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Queries");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D7").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

///////////////////////////////////////////Export value 4///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 var columnIndex = 10; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D9").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

  var columnIndex = 10; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Unanswered");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D9").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);

var columnIndex = 10; // Column 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Queries");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("D9").getValue();
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown");
  var a1Range = targetSS.getRange(5,columnIndex);
  var targetRange;
  if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
  else targetRange = targetSS.getRange(6,columnIndex);
  targetRange.setValue(sourceData);
```

Comment: Why are you copying the answer code into the question?

Comment: @TheMaster If you read the comment under my answer you will understand why it was changed

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 I still don't get it. I'm talking about this revision: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72776120/3 Are you referring to the same?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, his question wasn’t exactly the same as my answer, with really just a few ranges added from what i had, so i don’t believe it was necessary, but it was with the intention of letting me know what he currently had (since it was technically different than my answer) so i could better answer his question

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 I see. But it still does modify the question to the point where the answer and the question was almost the same. I think if OP valued his modifications enough to want to show, he  should add it as a answer instead, crediting you appropriately.

Comment: @TheMaster I agree with you, I was just clarifying why they made that change

Comment: My apologies. New to the site. Wasn't aware of the appropriate convention's. Will do so in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full script that should do what you are asking:

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function transferList() {

  var columnIndex = 1; // Column
  var columnIndexIncr = 3; //columnIndex increment per each target range
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheets = ["Cancellations", "Unanswered", "Queries"]; //Sheet names
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Deduction Breakdown"); //Target sheet
  var targetRanges = ["D5", "D6", "D7", "D9"]; //Target ranges
  var sourceData;
  var a1Range;
  var a1Row;
  var targetRange;

  for(var range of targetRanges) {
    for(var i in sourceSheets) {
      if(range == "D5") {a1Row = 2} else {a1Row = 5};
      sourceData = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheets[i]).getRange(range).getValue();
      if(sourceData == "N") {
        a1Range = targetSS.getRange(a1Row, columnIndex);
        if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
        else targetRange = targetSS.getRange((a1Row+1),columnIndex);
        targetRange.setValue(sourceData);
     }
    }
    columnIndex += columnIndexIncr;
  };

};
```

Please let me know if you have any issues with this. I tested this script in a test sheet and it should work. Please let me know if this was not the intended result

Comment: That's what I currently have. Whilst it does work, it means I have three loops for each cell I need to export to a different sheet. I have 9 'Exports' I need from each cell(s). I've edited the code from the og post to show a snippet of what I currently have. - As you can see it's very repetitive & takes a long, long time to execute.

Comment: @comiconor I have edited my answer to solve what I believe you are asking. It runs fairly quick for me. Please let me know if you have any issues

Comment: @kaitlynmm569Y, that is great, thank you! Much, much simpler to read. I've added in the other target ranges I'd need & it's working great. It still takes a good 50-60 seconds to execute. Would that be the best I'm going to get it? (I've edited by post to include what I have atm)

Comment: @comiconor chances are this formula is the fastest it’s going to get. you have several data ranges and so going through those is going to take time. a process like this is not as instantaneous as a regular Javascript script would be

Comment: thank you again. Very much appreciated. Two last questions if you don't mind.
Those cell referenced with the target ranges either contain the value "Y" or "N'. Firstly would it be possible for it to export the referenced cell if it contains "N"?
Secondly, as not all the target cells will contain the value "N", I assume this would make it execute faster?

Comment: @comiconor so only complete the script if the cell contains "N"? It would help it execute faster, though I'm not sure exactly how much faster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245993/discussion-between-kaitlynmm569-and-comiconor).

Answer (score 0):

#### multiple sheets same range

```
function transferList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dl = [{srcname:'Cancellations',srcrng:'D5',dstname:'Deduction Breakdown',dstrng:'A2'}];//fill in the remaining options
  dl.forEach(o => {
    let ssh = ss.getSheetByName(o.srcname);
    let srg = ssh.getRange(o.srcrng);
    let sda = srg.getValue();
    let dsh = ss.getSheetByName(o.dstname);
    let drg = dsh.getRange(o.dstrng);
    if(drg.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") {
      drg = drg,getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
    } else {
      drg = drg.offset(1,0);
    }
    drg.setValue(sda);
  })
}
```